# Calculating the numeric derivative

Tags: matlab, derivative

So i'm a little confounded by how to structure my problem.

So the assignment states as following:

Type a m-file numerical_derivative.m that performs numerical derivation. Use
it to calculate **f'(-3)** when **f(x) = 3x^2 /(ln(1-x))**

In the m-file you to use **h = 10^-6** and have the following mainfunction:

```
function y = numericalderivative (f, x)
% Calculates the numerical value in the case of f in punk x.
% --- Input ---
% f: function handle f(x)
% x: the point where the derivative is calculated
% --- output ---
% y: the numerical derivative of f on the point x
```

If I want to save it as a file and run the program in matlab, does't it make it redundant to use handles then?

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the answer to your homework, but perhaps a simpler example would help.

Consider the following problem

> Write a function named `fdiff` which takes the following two arguments:
>
> 1. A function `f` represented by a **function handle** which takes one argument,
> 2. and a point `x` which can be assumed to be in the domain of the `f`.
>
> Write `fdiff` so that it returns the value `f(x) - f(x-1)`

---

#### Solution (would be in the file named fdiff.m)

```
function result = fdiff(f, x)
    result = f(x) - f(x-1);
end
```

#### Example Use Cases

```
>> my_function1 = @(x) 3*x^2 /(log(1-x));
>> fdiff(my_function1, -3)
ans =
  -10.3477

>> my_function2 = @(x) x^2;
>> fdiff(my_function2, 5)
ans =
   9
```

What you've created with `fdiff` is **a function which takes another function as an input**. As you can see it doesn't just work for `3*x^2 /(log(1-x))` but any function you want to define.

The purpose of your assignment is to create something very similar, except instead of computing `f(x) - f(x-1)`, you are asked write a function which approximates `f'(x)`. Your use-case will be nearly identical to the first example except instead of `fdiff` your function will be named `numericalderivative`.

---

#### Note

In case it's not clear, the second example defines the `my_function2` as `x^2`. The value returned by `fdiff(my_function2, 5)` is therefore `5^2 - 4^2 = 9`.

Answer (score 0):

When you make this as a function file and run this in MATLAB without any input arguments i.e., 'f' and 'x', it will give you the error: 'not enough input arguments'. In order to run the file you have to type something like numericalderivative (3x^2 /(ln(1-x)), 5), which gives the value of the numerical derivative at x = 5.

Comment: `function y= numerical_derivative(f,x)
    h=10.^-6;
    func = @(x) (3*x^2)/log(1-x);
    x = -3;
    numericalderivative = @(x)((x+h)-(x))/h;
    dxdy = numericalderivative(func,x);
    end`

could't format the code. But this does't seem to work, but I don't see why?

Answer (score 0):

Functions and, in MATLAB function files are a simple implementation of the DRY programming method. You're being asked to create a function that takes a handle and an x file, then return the derivative of that function handle and that x value. The point of the function file is to be able to re-use your function with either multiple function handles or multiple x values. This is useful as it simply involves passing a function handle and a numeric value to a function.

In your case your script file or command window code would look something like:

```
func = @(x) (3*x^2)/log(1-x);
x = -3;
num_deriv = numericalderivative(func,x);
```

You should write the code to make the function *numericalderivative* work.

Comment: I think however that they want me derivative with respect to h. I.e that I should use the defintion of the derivative.
i.e dxdy =@(x) f(x+h) -f(x)/h;

Could I possibly add to the function 

dxdy= (3*x^2)/log(1-x); ?

Comment: I meant 
derivative = dxdy((3*x^2)/log(1-x));

Comment: I've now written it as: 


     function y= numerical_derivative(f,x)
     h=10.^-6;
     func = @(x) (3*x^2)/log(1-x);
     x = -3;
     numericalderivative = @(x,h)((x+h)-(x))/h;
     dxdy = numericalderivative(func,x);
     end


But still does't work, am I using to few arguments? Seems that I can't format my code. sorry

Comment: It looks like you need to pass another parameter to the function. The rest of it isn't matlab based and is just your understanding of numeric methods. Specifically x (point of analysis) vs h (step size).